# Como posso deixar o baseURL dinâmico em React

Tags: react, axios

Olá pessoal tudo bem? Estou com uma dúvida e gostaria de ajuda, estou utilizando o React para fazer uma página web no qual qualquer usuário possa utiliza-la para consumir APIs. Para fazer isso estou usando o axios, a minha dúvida é a seguinte, a idéia da página é o usuário utilizar o input para digitar o endereço da API que ele quer consumir clicando em enviar os dados é retornado para ele. Porém após pesquisar muito só encontrei o tutoriais com o baseURL do axios com endereços fixos, não sei como faço para recuperar o estado do que o usuário digitou e fazer a requisição á ele, ou seja, deixar o baseURL dinâmico. Segue abaixo meu código e a página, desde já agradeço.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export class Home extends Component {
 static displayName = Home.name;
 constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        url: '',
        result: '',
        method: 'post',
        token: '',
        body: '',
    };
}

UrlFunction = (eventUrl) => { this.setState({ url: eventUrl.target.value }) }
MethodFunction = (eventMethod) => { this.setState({ method: eventMethod.target.value }) }
TokenFunction = (eventToken) => { this.setState({ token: eventToken.target.value }) }
JsonFunction = (eventBody) => { this.setState({ body: eventBody.target.value }) }

async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await (await axios.get(this.state.url)).data
    const result = JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4)
    console.log(result)
    this.setState({ result })
}

render() {
    const { result } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.componentDidMount} >
                <select value={this.state.method} onChange={this.MethodFunction}>
                    <option value="get">GET</option>
                    <option value="post">POST</option>
                    <option value="patch">PATCH</option>
                    <option value="put">PUT</option>
                    <option value="delete">DELETE</option>
                </select>
                <label>
                    URL
            <input type="text" name="url" value={this.state.url} onChange={this.UrlFunction} />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Token : Bearer
            <input type="text" name="token" value={this.state.token} onChange={this.TokenFunction} />
                </label>

                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </form>

            <textarea value={this.state.body} onChange={this.JsonFunction} cols="75" rows="20">

            </textarea>

            <textarea value={result} cols="75" rows="20" readOnly disabled></textarea>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não entendi, porque você já está gravando um novo estado para url? não entendi mesmo

Comment: no state acima eu deixei a url iniciada só para demonstrar mesmo, a idéia é deixa-la vazia para o usuário preencher.

Answer (score 1):

Para mudar a `baseURL` é necessário criar uma nova instância do Axios com `.create`. Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```js
// config/axios.js
let axiosApiServer = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000', // baseURL inicial
  timeout: 15000,
});

export const getAxiosApiServer = (baseURL) => {
  if (baseURL && baseURL !== axiosApiServer.defaults.baseURL) {
    // Criamos uma nova instância apenas se foi passado uma nova baseURL
    // se ela for diferente da baseURL atual

    axiosAppServer = axios.create({
      baseURL: apiUrl,
      timeout: 15000, // Não esqueça de passar as outras opções
    });
  }

  return axiosAppServer;
};
```

```
// components/Component.js
import { getAxiosApiServer } from '../config/axios';
 
export const Component = () => {
  function fetch() {
    // Para realizar um GET, faça:
    const data = (await getAxiosApiServer().get('/endpoint')).data;
    
     // lembrando que você pode mudar a baseURL assim:
    const data = (await getAxiosApiServer('http://localhost:3000').get('/endpoint')).data;
  }
};
```

Eu uso uma função parecida para mudança da `baseURL` e também de `token` (que é passado pelo `headers`), então é possível adaptá-la para qualquer configuração do `axios.create`.

Answer (score 1):

O próprio `axios.create()` é dinamico, não precisa criar um módulo exagerado proprio, uma instancia do axios só vai usar a `baseURL` quando a URL atual não contiver o "protocolo", ou seja quando **não** for a URL inteira, nos métodos `axios.get`, `axios.post`, etc.

Só é usado o `baseURL` quando se [cria uma instanciar](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance), algo como:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Também no seu código atual isso não existe, logo não tem `baseURL`, então é só passar a URL inteira diretamente:

```
// Se for Node.js 10, se for os mais recentes use o "import"
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://stackoverflow.com.br/').then(function () {
    console.log("success");
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
});
```

Se você criar uma instância mas passe a URL inteira o próprio `axios` vai entender que não é o `baseURL`:

```
// Se for Node.js 10, se for os mais recentes use o "import"
const axios = require('axios');

const axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    timeout: 16000
});

// Vai requisitar o https://www.google.com.br/, ignorando o baseURL
axios.get('https://www.google.com.br').then(function (response) {
    console.log('success', response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
});

// Vai requisitar o https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518921, "considerado" o baseURL
axios.get('users/1518921').then(function (response) {
    console.log("success", response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error', error.message);
});
```

Ou usando `await`:

```
// Vai requisitar o https://www.google.com.br/, ignorando o baseURL
try {
    let response = await axios.get('https://www.google.com.br');

    console.log('success', response.data);
} catch (ee) {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
}

// Vai requisitar o https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518921, "considerado" o baseURL
try {
    let response = await axios.get('users/1518921');

    console.log('success', response.data);
} catch (ee) {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
}
```

Para resumir, se não usou ou mesmo que tenha usado instância basta passar a URL inteira em:

```
const response = await (await axios.get(this.state.url)).data
```

Answer (score 0):

O que fala a documentação do Axios:

### Config Defaults

"Você pode especificar padrões de configuração que serão aplicados a cada solicitação."

### Global axios defaults

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

### Custom instance defaults

```
// Definir padrões de configuração ao criar a instância
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});

// Alterar os padrões após a criação da instância
instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Ou seja, após a criação de uma instância do axios, você pode alterar a baseUrl dela da seguinte forma:

```
myInstance.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
```

Fonte: https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults